# Add separator between foreach returned values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have the following foreach returning values :

```
@foreach($content['order'] as $products)
    <tr>
        <td><span>{{ $products->Type }} {{ $products->Nom }} {{ $products->{'# Personnes'} }} {{ $products->Inscription }} {{ $products->{'Décoration Chocolat et fruits'} }} {{ $products->{'Décoration petites fleurs'} }} {{ $products->Décoration }} {{ $products->{'Nombre de sandwiches'} }} {{ $products->Poids }} {{ $products->{'Assortiment 1'} }} {{ $products->{'Assortiment 2'} }} {{ $products->{'Assortiment 3'} }} {{ $products->{'Assortiment 4'} }} {{ $products->{'Couleur Ruban'} }} {{ number_format($products->Prix, 2) }} {{ number_format($products->Supplément, 2) }} {{ number_format($products->{'Supplément décoration'}, 2) }} {{ number_format($products->Total, 2) }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I would like to add a separator between each returned values (except for the last).

I added

```
.' | '

{{ $products->Type.' | ' }} {{ $products->Nom.' | ' }} {{ $products->{'# Personnes'}.' | ' }} {{ $products->Inscription.' | ' }} {{ $products->{'Décoration Chocolat et fruits'}.' | ' }} {{ $products->{'Décoration petites fleurs'}.' | ' }} {{ $products->Décoration.' | ' }} {{ $products->{'Nombre de sandwiches'}.' | ' }} {{ $products->Poids.' | ' }} {{ $products->{'Assortiment 1'}.' | ' }} {{ $products->{'Assortiment 2'}.' | ' }} {{ $products->{'Assortiment 3'}.' | ' }} {{ $products->{'Assortiment 4'}.' | ' }} {{ $products->{'Couleur Ruban'}.' | ' }} {{ number_format($products->Prix, 2).' | ' }} {{ number_format($products->Supplément, 2).' | ' }} {{ number_format($products->{'Supplément décoration'}, 2).' | ' }} {{ number_format($products->Total, 2) }}
```

Problem I have is that the separator is added even when no value is returned

```
Pie | Chocolate | 2-3 servings | Text | Decoration chocolate | Decoration flowers | | | | | | | | | 19.00 | 5.00 | 0.00 | 24.00
```

How can I print a separator only if a value is returned.

Thanks

Comment: _How can I print a separator only if a value is returned...._ Use a simple `if` condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@if(isset($products->Type)) {{ $products->Type. '|' }}  @endif
```

This is an example of your first row how you can handle it. You check if exists and if it does you `echo` the result concatenating a separator on it.

*small thing, mind your `span` tag, you are not closing it in the code you provided.*

Comment: Thanks @pr1nc3 your solution work and feets my needs (thanks for the span to). Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator as a short hand for the same,

```
{{ !empty($products->Type) ? $products->Type.' | ': '' }}
```

Do this for all the fields

Answer (score 0):

There's several way of going about this, but one quite dynamic way would be to fetch all the values into an array instead, filter it for non-empty values and implode it.

We'd be using standard PHP, which you can do within blades.

```php
<?php
foreach($content['order'] as $products) {
    $values = [];
    $values[] = $products->Type;
    $values[] = $products->Nom;
    $values[] = $products->{'# Personnes'};
    $values[] = $products->Inscription;
    $values[] = $products->{'Décoration Chocolat et fruits'};
    $values[] = $products->{'Décoration petites fleurs'};
    $values[] = $products->Décoration;
    $values[] = $products->{'Nombre de sandwiches'};
    $values[] = $products->Poids;
    $values[] = $products->{'Assortiment 1'};
    $values[] = $products->{'Assortiment 2'};
    $values[] = $products->{'Assortiment 3'};
    $values[] = $products->{'Assortiment 4'};
    $values[] = $products->{'Couleur Ruban'};
    $values[] = number_format($products->Prix, 2);
    $values[] = number_format($products->Supplément, 2);
    $values[] = number_format($products->{'Supplément décoration'}, 2);
    $values[] = number_format($products->Total, 2);

    echo "<td>".implode(" | ", array_filter($values))."</td>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn into array, filter empty values and implode with an " | " string

```
 {{join("|", array_filter([
 $products->Type ,
 $products->Nom ,
 $products->{'# Personnes'} ,
 $products->Inscription ,
 $products->{'Décoration Chocolat et fruits'} ,
 $products->{'Décoration petites fleurs'} ,
 $products->Décoration ,
 $products->{'Nombre de sandwiches'} ,
 $products->Poids ,
 $products->{'Assortiment 1'} ,
 $products->{'Assortiment 2'} ,
 $products->{'Assortiment 3'} ,
 $products->{'Assortiment 4'} ,
 $products->{'Couleur Ruban'} ,
 number_format($products->Prix, 2) ,
 number_format($products->Supplément, 2) ,
 number_format($products->{'Supplément décoration'}, 2) ,
 number_format($products->Total, 2)
 ]))}}
```